# ON DELETE SET NULL TRIGGER DELETE

Tags: mysql

I have created a trigger to delete a row from `orders` when the `user_id` and `restaurant_id` are set to `null`.

```
delimiter //
create trigger order_delete
before update on orders
for each row
if new.user_id is null and new.restaurant_id is null then
delete from orders where order_id = new.order_id;
end if;
//
delimiter ;
```

`user_id` and `restaurant_id` are foreign keys from two other tables and will be set to null when they are deleted from their respective tables. However, when I tried deleting them from their tables it does not execute the trigger. So I still have an order with two `user_id = NULL` and `restaurant_id = NULL`remaining in my orders table. Does anyone know why my trigger is not triggering?

Comment: sorry typo in the first line. "....delete **a row** from ...."

Comment: Surely, you have the ability to edit your post by clicking on the "edit" link just below the body text.

Comment: Why would you want to do it this way anyway?  IMHO it is better to explicitly delete data which is no longer needed in the application, doing it this way (or not in this instance) can cause confusion and sometimes unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) says:

> Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers

Therefore, no mtter what trigger you create, it is not going to be called when a value is set to null via cascade.

If you only want to delete a record if both fields are set to null, then you have to perform this action from the application code, you cannot rely on database automation.

Just a side note: you should not delete orders from your system, since they are the basis of your financial transactions and you can get into trouble with the tax authorities and the external financial auditors for doing that.

Answer (score -1):

You want that trigger to be fired when `user_id` and `restaurant_id` are set to `NULL`?

In that case, you should use:

```
delimiter //
create trigger order_delete
after update on orders
for each row
if new.user_id is null and new.restaurant_id is null then
delete from orders where order_id = new.order_id;
end if;
//
delimiter ;
```

Using the keyword `after` instead of `before` means the trigger will be fired after the fields are set to `null`. Using `before`, the trigger will be fired when `user_id` and `restaurant_id` still have their previous values. In that case, the condition in the `if` statement is never true.

Comment: Cascaded actions by foreign keys do to activate triggers in MySQL.